# Python bug I guess, have a look

Tags: python

doing:

```
>>>'a'*20 is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

gives

```
>>>True
```

while doing:

```
>>>'a'*21 is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

gives

```
>>>False
```

Whats going on here? Is this a bug?

Comment: There is no bug. Python don't create new objects in memory for short strings and int numbers less then 256.

Comment: just to add to @NobbyNobbs : `is` implies the same memory object, the correct "equality check" is with `==`

Comment: check this out it will give an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Answer (score 1):

For smaller objects python is reusing the allocated memory.
But for larger objects the reference is changing.
Do check [this](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=x%3D'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'%0Ay%3D'a'*21%0At%20%3D%20'a'*20%0Au%20%3D%20'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'&cumulative=true&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=true&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

```
x='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
y='a'*21
t= 'a'*20
u = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Here t and u reference the same string but x and y do not so the object comparison isn't working.

Comment: Please refrain from answering obvious FAQs. If you find that the answers to the proposed duplicates are not good enough, post your answer there.